# Routing in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following problem: I wanna write a ASP.Net Project where Users can register and login and after it also add or delete things. For the User i have a UserController and for the Map a MapController. I wanna have the possibility to write in the URL localhost:port/User/Login so a User can login via the User Controller or when i want to add a Shop i wanna write localhost:port/map/Add_Shop and so on.

This is my UserController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Soft_Arch_WebAPI.Models;

namespace Soft_Arch_WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public String Register()
        {
            return "Hier werden User registriert";
            //Get Values from Form and Send to Service
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public String Login()
        {
            return "Hier werden User eingeloggt";
            //Get Values from Form and Send to Service
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public String ResetPWD(int ID, String Password)
        {
            return "Hier können User Ihr Passwort ändern";
            //Get Values from Form and Send to Service
        }
    }
}
```

And this my Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Soft_Arch_WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "user",
                  pattern: "User/Register/");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "user",
                pattern: "User/Login/");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "user",
                pattern: "User/ResetPWD/");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "map",
                pattern: "{controller=Map}/Add_Shop/");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "map",
                pattern: "{controller=Map}/Edit_Shop/");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "favourite",
                pattern: "{controller=Favourite}/Add_Favourite/");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "favourite",
                pattern: "{controller=Favourite}/Delete_Favourite/");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "poi",
                pattern: "{controller=Poi}/Add_Poi/");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "poi",
                pattern: "{controller=Poi}/Delete_Poi/");

            });

        }
    }
}
```

How can i set the Routes as mentioned Previous that i can acess for example the login function in Usercontroller via localhost:port/User/Login and so on.

Comment: There are numerous resources out these explaining how to configure routing for .net core. What have you tried and what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

@Simon Seems like we are using attribute routing for User Controller. We can make use of attributes for action method login in controller itself like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Soft_Arch_WebAPI.Models;

namespace Soft_Arch_WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("Register")]
        public String Register()
        {
            return "Hier werden User registriert";
            //Get Values from Form and Send to Service
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public String Login()
        {
            return "Hier werden User eingeloggt";
            //Get Values from Form and Send to Service
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public String ResetPWD(int ID, String Password)
        {
            return "Hier können User Ihr Passwort ändern";
            //Get Values from Form and Send to Service
        }
    }
}
```

Since we are using attribute routing for user controller, we can remove entry for User controller from Startup.cs. 
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Hemant Kumar has said that you need to configure [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing-with-httpverb-attributes) manually insead of configuring `UseEndpoints` in asp.net core web api.From the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-3.1#attribute-routing-requirement)

> The `[ApiController]` attribute makes attribute routing a requirement.
>
> Actions are inaccessible via conventional routes defined by
> `UseEndpoints`, `UseMvc`, or `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute` in Startup.Configure.